# How to send active worksheet or chosen workseet in attachment?

Tags: excel, vba, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a form.

I tried to replace thisWorkbook with ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Form").

```
Sub send_mail()
Dim outlookOBJ As Object
Dim mItem As Object
Set outlookOBJ = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set mItem = outlookOBJ.createItem(olMailItem)
With mItem
    .to = "miketheemperor@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "test"
    .body = "test"
    .attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    .display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip but I don't fully understand it. so do I have to re-do the entire code?

Comment: Yes, you cannot just attach a single worksheet as it is not a "file" - Instead, you define a range, and then turn that into HTML that you can include in the email as that link shows. Your other option would be to save the current workbook, delete all the sheets except for the one you want, then save it with a new name, attach that new file, and the close that workbook and open the original one with the other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like copying the sheet to a new workbook, add that new workbook, and then delete it.

```
Dim outlookOBJ As Object
Dim mItem As Object
Set outlookOBJ = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set mItem = outlookOBJ.createItem(olMailItem)


Dim TempPath As String
TempPath = "C:\Temp\TempWorkbook.xlsx" 'a path where will save a temporary workbook

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form").Copy 'this will copy the worksheet FORM to a NEW workbook. That new WB will be the active one
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs TempPath
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

With mItem
    .to = "miketheemperor@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "test"
    .body = "test"
    .attachments.Add TempPath
    Kill TempPath 'we delete the temporary Workbook
    .display
End With
```